# int array might not have been initialized

Tags: java, class, initialization

```
class MyClass {
    public int[] arr;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    MyClass thing;
    thing.arr = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

Error: `variable thing might not have been initialized`

...what? I'm literally assigning it an array, why is it giving me this error?

Comment: The compiler is not saying that `arr` might not have been initialized. It's saying that `thing` might not have been initialized - and it's right. You never assign a value to `thing`. You probably want `MyClass thing = new MyClass();`

Comment: MyClass thing = new MyClass();

Comment: I had tried that but got `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`

Comment: You wouldn't get that error with the change that Kai-Sheng and I have suggested.

Comment: @JonSkeet It does though `error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context` and shows `MyClass thing = new MyClass();` with a little arrow pointing to the `new`

Comment: @user525966: Ah - I see, that'll be because `MyClass` is an inner class. (It was unclear because you haven't provided complete code.) I suggest you move `MyClass` so that it's *not* an inner class - inner classes introduce all kinds of extra complexity into things, and if you're just starting out they're rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int[] data;

    public MyClass(int[] data) {
       this.data = data;
    }

    public int[] getData() {
       return data;
    }
}
```

and for your main

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
     MyClass myClass = new MyClass(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myClass.getData());
}
```